# Multi step popup tracking using Google tag Manager virtual page url

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking

I'm tracking multi-step popup but stuck. Let me explain requirement:

I have a website `example.com` and there is a popup with 3 steps (I can open it from any page of the site). I want to track each step because in every step there is a multiselect option (for this I'm using custom dimension.

I created tag with trigger in GTM and setup Goal/funnel in GA. It is not working properly.

Virtual urls are like:

- `/virtual/step1`
- `/virtual/step2`
- `/virtual/success`

According to me, When I complete first step it should show me `/virtual/step1` in real time GA tracking but it doesn't

I can only see the `/virtual/step1` when I complete the 3 steps and there I believe I should see `/virtual/success` instead of `/virtual/step1`

Hope I'm able to explain my problem.

Can anyone please suggestion me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Do you see the virtual URLs being reported in the GA Behaviour > Site Content > All pages report? What sort of tag and trigger did you setup in GTM?